# How to define a rule in functions.php that ONLY disables the default wp functionality that undesirably changes '&' to '#038;'?

Tags: php, functions, url-rewriting, redirect, urls

I use a quick redirects plugin and it's changing my URLs after the fact and thereby breaking some of my links. I never want wordpress to change `&` to `#038;`.

There is an unwanted solution to turn off all `wp_texturize` by placing:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

I don't want to disable everything, just the `&` conversion in URLs.

I can physically modify `wp-includes/formatting.php` by commenting out this line, but it didn't work:

```
$content = preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z1-4]{1,8};)/i', '&#038;$1', $content);
```

I don't want to do that even if it did work, which it didn't, otherwise I'd have to do it again on every wp upgrade. But actually I tried it and it didn't fix it.

For now I added a 301 redirect into htaccess which worked.

What is a permanent line of code to add to functions.php to permanently disable wordpress modifying `&` to `#038;`?

Comment: `wptexturize` doesn't run on URLs, I'm not sure what the content has to do with URLs, have you skipped over a part of the explanation? **Have you raised this problem with the quick redirects plugin? 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here and not in this stacks scope**. Have you reported this as a bug to the plugin?

Comment: The redirect is followed from a link IN the post, so it is WP adding this, not the plugin.

Comment: so your URLs are still working, it's how they're being displayed in the content that is the problem, hence `wp_texturize`, but that filter does not modify links, think about it, you can enter an ampersand in a link in the editor and it doesn't get broken, so either your site is unique and has code that other WordPress sites do not have, or there is something else about how these URLs are being inserted into the content that needs to be shared. _Again though, have you contacted the plugins support route or asked other users of that plugin?_